# Creating Azure AD Domain

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm creating an instance of Azure AD Domain Services and following the steps found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started

In the section about DNS it states:

> Network name conflicts: Ensure that the DNS domain name you have chosen for the managed domain does not already exist in the virtual network. Specifically, check whether:
>   You already have an Active Directory domain with the same DNS domain name on the virtual network.
>   The virtual network where you plan to enable the managed domain has a VPN connection with your on-premises network. In this scenario, ensure you don't have a domain with the same DNS domain name on your on-premises network.
>   You have an existing cloud service with that name on the virtual network.

I'm not quite sure I understand the restriction here, my Azure Active Directory has a custom domain of [mydomain].com. Is this saying I cannot use the [mydomain].com domain for the DNS entry when creating an "Azure AD Domain Services" instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is talking about Active Directory, not Azure Active Directory.

If you already have an AD domain setup on VMs in the same VNET or have a VPN connection to an on-premises network with an AD domain with the same domain name, you will run into conflicts as AAD DS will also register the domain.

If you are only using Azure AD without a connection to on-prem AD, you are fine.